# How do you read loops?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

What is the thought process when evaluating a loop? I really have no idea how the shell gets these answers (`A`: `12`, `B`: `2`, `C`: `4`, `D`: `6`).

```
A, B, C, D = 0, 0, 0, 0

while A <= 10:
    A += 2
    if A%3 == 0:
        B += 1
    else:
        C += 1
    D += 1
```

Comment: First of all you need to know what are the initial values of the variables, which are not stated in your snippet.

Comment: You may want to check your post in the Preview panel, instead of closing your eyes and hit "Send".

Comment: Also, please re-indent your code.  Indentation is *extremely* important to understand a python control structure.

Comment: The edit just made does not produce the output indicated by the asker.  `D += 1` needs to be at the top level of the loop.

Comment: Alright i think i fixed all the issues, my bad

Comment: Just read the code. In Python reading the code is 9 times out of 10 enough to understand what the code does.

Comment: Which value(s) are hard for you to understand?

Comment: I dont understand how the shell produces c = 4 and d=6

Comment: Take a pen and paper, create a table with columns for all your variables, and start manually evaluating your program, updating the relevant table column whenever a variable value changes.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is getting downvotes. It's a valid question for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can read it more easily if you break it down:

```
A = 0

while A <= 10:
    A += 2
```

Can you read this? Do you understand how it gets to `12`?

```
A, D = 0, 0

while A <= 10:
    A += 2
    D += 1
```

Also including `D` should not make it any harder.

Can you read and understand the `if`-statement by itself?

```
if A%3 == 0:
    B += 1
else:
    C += 1
```

How about when it is inside the loop?

```
A, B, C, D = 0, 0, 0, 0

while A <= 10:
    A += 2
    if A%3 == 0:
        B += 1
    else:
        C += 1
    D += 1
```

`B` and `C` are related; exactly one of them are incremented in each iteration, so they should add up to the same as `D`, which they do.

Do you have any specific problems reading and understanding this now? :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good. I would highly recommend going through things with a pen and paper to make sure you understand what's going on.

Using `print` inside the loop is also useful to see what is going on while your program runs.

```
A,B,C,D = 0,0,0,0

while A <= 10:
    A += 2
    if A%3 == 0:
        B += 1
    else:
        C += 1
    D += 1
    print "A =", A, " B =", B, " C =", C, " D =", D
```

The output shows you the values of `A, B, C, D` at the end of every loop iteration.

```
A = 2  B = 0  C = 1  D = 1
A = 4  B = 0  C = 2  D = 2
A = 6  B = 1  C = 2  D = 3
A = 8  B = 1  C = 3  D = 4
A = 10  B = 1  C = 4  D = 5
A = 12  B = 2  C = 4  D = 6
```

You can see that:

- `A` gets incremented by `2` every loop iteration
- `B` gets incremented by `1` *IF* `A` is divisible by `3`, that is `A%3 == 0`
- `C` gets incremented by `1` *IF* `A` is *NOT* divisible by `3`
- `D` gets incremented by `1` every loop iteration

When it comes to loops, you can think of the collection of indented code as a single "chunk" of code that gets executed once for every repetition of the loop. The formal term for this code chunk is a [block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29). It also applies to `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: This made it very clear! Thank you I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

The body of the `while` loop will execute 6 times (for `A=0,2,4,6,8,10`).

- At each iteration, `A` is incremented by 2, so after the first statement
  within the loop it has values `2,4,6,8,10,12`.
- `B` is incremented by one twice (when `A=6` and `A=12`);
- `C` is incremented by one for the remaining values of `A`.
- `D` is incremented every time round the loop.

Hence, after the loop, `A=12`, `B=2`, `C=4` and `D=6`.